# Is the secondary current in a transformer dependent upon the load resistance?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

Is the secondary current in a transformer dependent upon the load resistance? If no, can we use a small(handheld) generator,with a step up transformer to power a house? Please give the mathematical expression of secondary current....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secondary current in a typical transformer with the secondary connected to some load does depend on the load impedance.

If an ideal transformer has primary voltage $V_1$, secondary voltage $V_2$, turns ratio $N$ and the secondary is connected to a load impedance $Z_L$, the secondary (load) current is

$$I_2 = \frac{V_2}{Z_L}=N\frac{V_1}{Z_L}.$$

Comment: Arigatou sensei :)

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge upon Puk's answer, the amount of electrical power needed to run a house is of order ~several thousand watts, which is more than ten times greater than what you could possibly generate using your arms to turn a crank.

Comment: Thank u very much.....